Is "needs details or clarity" the correct close reason for my question?
My question at Is there a set of vectors that is linearly dependent but spans $\mathbb{R}^3$? has been closed with the reason:

This question needs details or clarity.

Is this the correct close reason? I added details about the context in which I was asking the question and my question (I think) was precise too. Sure enough, multiple kind members of this community answered my question too! So I'm trying to understand what more details or clarity I could've added to the question.
I understand that the question is trivial (and silly in hindsight) but the question was not closed as "too trivial" (which is expected because there is no such close reason). The question was closed as "need details or clarity". It would help me for my future questions if someone could kindly explain what details exactly need to be added to this question?

I just voted to reopen the question. While the question is very basic with immediate answers, I think the question is sufficiently clear with sufficient context. I also think the question is somewhat reasonable for someone just learning these abstract ideas, who doesn't yet have the mental pictures and ideas needed to easily resolve it (e.g. adding vectors to a set of vectors does not reduce the spanning set of the vectors, and adding vectors to a basis creates a linearly dependent set). Maybe revise it slightly and/or add more context to get it on the front page for others to see it again.

the answer is yes, because you should include research and other details for this

Even if one disagrees with that majority choice of close reason, it is surely a duplicate so should remain closed. Please search for answers before asking questions. $\ \ $

@BillDubuque In that case, can the question be closed as a duplicate with the duplicate question mentioned in the close reason?

Of course, but that is usually wasted effort for (arguable) PSQs that are also dupes of FAQs because they usually add nothing novel to our knowledge base.

It is a low-quality question that could be closed for several different reasons. "Needs details" works. I don't see why this would be reopened, but I guess 5 people found some reason to do it.
